# How do I print the value of an array with the index of the array in argument of my function?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, batch-file, set, echo

I am using three functions. One is getting the list of drives:

```
REM list the drives
:list_disk
ECHO List of drives

set n=0
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk get DeviceID^') do (
    set nom[!n!]=%%a
    set /A n+=1
)
set /A "N=%n%/2"
FOR /L %%i IN (0,1,%N%) DO (
    echo !nom[%%i]!
    echo/
)
EXIT /B 0
```

The second is proposing to the user to choose which drives should be processed in the next function:

```
REM choice of drives
:choix nom
echo Choice
FOR /L %%i IN (0,1,%N%) DO (
    echo Do you want to raise the drive !nom[%%i]!
    echo (y/n^) ?

    SET c=n
    SET /P c=
    if !c!==y call :HASH i
)

EXIT /B 0
```

And the last one uses the index of the array to process the chosen drive:

```
REM fingerprinting
:HASH
ECHO Fingerprinting in progress ...
echo !nom[%%i]!

ECHO progam integration fingerprint :

EXIT /B 0
```

The problem is the last `echo !nom[%%i]!` which doesn't work as expected.

Why does it not print which drive is selected?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a case of a linefeed from WMIC's output being defined to the last index? - that's the entire reason the macro I posted in answer to your last question contains a secondary for loop during capture of command output - to handle this edge case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is caused by passing the string `i` instead of the value of loop variable `i` to the subroutine `HASH` by using `if !c!==y call :HASH i` instead of `if !c!==y call :HASH %%i` and referencing the value of the loop loop variable with `echo !nom[%%i]!` not existing at all in the context of the subroutine execution instead of the value passed to the subroutine with `echo !nom[%1]!`.

But there are several other problems with this code like ignoring the last drive because of indexing the drives wrong or usage of `set /p` although using `choice` would be definitely better here as more fail-safe and secure.

It is also advisable to reference executables with well-known path in batch files with their fully qualified file names making the execution of the batch file faster as `cmd.exe` does not need to search for the executables using the environment variables `PATH` and `PATHEXT` and so avoiding lots of file system accesses during execution of the batch file.

A better code is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
rem list the drives
:list_disk
echo List of drives
echo(
set n=-1
for /F "tokens=2 delims==:" %%i in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe LOGICALDISK GET DeviceID /VALUE') do (
    set /A n+=1
    set nom[!n!]=%%i
)
for /L %%i IN (0,1,%n%) do echo !nom[%%i]!:

rem choice of drives
:choix nom
echo(
echo Choice
echo(
for /L %%i in (0,1,%n%) do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C NY /N /M "Do you want to raise the drive !nom[%%i]!: (Y/N)?"
    if errorlevel 2 call :HASH %%i
)
exit /B 0

rem fingerprinting
:HASH
echo(
echo Fingerprinting in progress for drive !nom[%1]!: ...
rem Call of the command to generate the fingerprint for drive !nom[%1]!
echo program integration fingerprint:
echo(
exit /B 0
```

The first **FOR** loop assigns now only the drive letter without colon to the environment variable with `name[x]` whereby `x` is in range 0 to `n`, for example `0` to `3` on four drives output by `wmic`.

The usage of `wmic` option `/VALUE` and the `for /F` options `tokens=2` and `delims==:` avoids the problem with wrong parsed UTF-16 Little Endian output of `wmic` by `for`. The command `for` interprets `0D 00 0A 00` (UTF-16 LE encoded carriage return + line-feed) wrong as `0D 0D 0A` (carriage return + carriage return + line-feed). This wrong Unicode text parsing does not matter because of assigning to the loop variable `i` only the drive letter between `DeviceID=` and `:` from the output of `wmic`.

Therefore the number of processed lines and created environment variables assigned to `n` is correct and no division by two is necessary anymore. `n` is now the last index number used on definition of an environment variable with a drive letter.

The **FOR** loop for the choice uses now the command **CHOICE** to prompt the user for the Yes/No choice. The letters `Y` in the command line can be replaced by `O` for the French version, i.e. using `/C NO` and `(O/N)`. For more details see my answer on [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564)

Another solution using `mountvol.exe` instead of `wmic.exe` which is not available anymore in Windows 11 starting with build 22572:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
rem list the drives
:list_disk
echo List of drives
echo(
set n=-1
for /F "delims=: " %%i in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\mountvol.exe ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe ":\" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\sort.exe') do (
    set /A n+=1
    set nom[!n!]=%%i:
)
for /L %%i IN (0,1,%n%) do echo !nom[%%i]!

rem choice of drives
:choix nom
echo(
echo Choice
echo(
for /L %%i in (0,1,%n%) do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C NY /N /M "Do you want to raise the drive !nom[%%i]! (Y/N)?"
    if errorlevel 2 call :HASH %%i
)
exit /B 0

rem fingerprinting
:HASH
echo(
echo Fingerprinting in progress for drive !nom[%1]! ...
rem Call of the command to generate the fingerprint for drive !nom[%1]!
echo program integration fingerprint:
echo(
exit /B 0
```

In this case the environment variables are defined with drive letter and colon as the colon is already added on line `set nom[!n!]=%%i:`. It would be also possible to use `delims=\`  instead of `delims=:`  and `set nom[!n!]=%%i` to get the environment variables defined with drive letter and colon.

Another solution using `fsutil.exe` to get the drives with colon for assigning them to the environment variables is:

```
for /F "tokens=1*" %%i in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\fsutil.exe fsinfo drives') do for %%k in (%%j) do for /F "delims=\" %%l in ("%%k") do (
    set /A n+=1
    set nom[!n!]=%%l
)
```

`for /F "delims=\" %%l in ("%%k") do` could be omitted and `set nom[!n!]=%%l` changed to `set nom[!n!]=%%k` to get the drives with colon and with the backslash assigned to the environment variables, i.e. `C:\`, `D:\`, ... instead of `C:`, `D:`, ...

The other lines of this third solution getting the drives are the same as in second solution with `mountvol.exe`.

**Note:** The solution using `fsutil.exe` expects an output like:

```
Drives: C:\ D:\ R:\
```

That is the output on an English Windows. If there are multiple space separated words left to first output drive ending finally with `:` instead of `Drives:` it is better to use `"tokens=1* delims=:"` instead of just `"tokens=1*"` in first `for /F` command to ignore the string left to first colon in output of `fsutil.exe` instead of left to first space and process the remaining part of the line with the space separated drives with the second `for` command.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `choice /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?` ... not used explicitly, but run implicitly by `cmd.exe`
- `exit /?`
- `find /?`
- `for /?`
- `fsutil /?`
- `fsutil fsinfo /?`
- `mountvol /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `sort /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic logicaldisk /?`
- `wmic logicaldisk get /?`